# Is there a C# example of Particle Swarm Optimization PSO using Encog 3.2?

Tags: encog

I seriously searched hard for a Particle Swarm Optimization example using Encoq 3.2 C# version.  I would be very appreciative if someone could share one.  My array type is continuous.

Thanks,
Dan Hickman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encog uses Particle Swarm (PSO) as a means of training a neural network.  So it is really just another trainer that can be swapped in for backprop, rprop and the others.  There is an example included:

https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/blob/master/ConsoleExamples/Examples/XOR/XORPSO.cs